# Why is Python still garbage-collecting my Tkinter image?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm aware that this is a question that has been asked before on this site. However, **I've made an honest attempt to implement the solutions put forward in those answers**, and I'm still running into the same problem: **Python seems to keep garbage-collecting my image**, and I get an empty slot in my window where the image ought to be, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

This is the part of my code where I attempt to import an image:

```py
def make_top_title(self):
    result = Frame(self.top)
    text_lbl = Label(result, text="Proserpine",
                     font=(main_font, title_pt, "bold"))
    arms_image = PhotoImage("icon.png")
    arms_lbl = Label(result, image=arms_image, height=200)
    arms_lbl.image = arms_image
    arms_lbl.pack()
    text_lbl.pack()
    return result
```

You'll notice that I've already attempted to use the trick of preserving the image by anchoring it onto a property of a label object. You may also notice, from the attached screenshot, that I have no problem importing a custom icon - using the same image file - for this window.

I'm happy to share any more code from this program, as required.

---

A couple of people have suggested I share a bit more of my code. This is the whole file in which the code above is located:

```py
### This code holds a class which allows the user to inspect a the coldstore
### object attached to its parent.

# GUI imports.
from tkinter import *

# Custom imports.
from sibstructures import data_storage
from sibstructures.numerals import index_to_label_column, \
                                   index_to_label_row, \
                                   index_to_label_layer

# Imports
import time
from threading import Thread

# Local constants.
main_font = "Arial"
title_pt = 60
subtitle_pt = 30
big_pt = 20
standard_pt = 15
diddy_pt = 10
standard_pad = 10
inner_pad = 5
tile_width = 15
details_height = 10
details_width = 30
grid_border = 5
spot_stack_width = tile_width+5

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

# The class in question.
class CS_Viewer:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent_window = self.parent.get_top()
    self.code = self.parent.coldstore.code
    self.parent.coldstore.reconstruct()
    self.max_max_layers = self.parent.coldstore.get_max_max_layers()
    self.layer = 0
    self.top = Frame(self.parent_window)
    self.top_title = self.make_top_title()
    self.subtitle = Label(self.top, text="code="+self.code,
                          font=(main_font, subtitle_pt, "bold"))
    self.main_container = Frame(self.top)
    self.spot_grid = Spot_Grid(self, self.main_container)
    self.box_details = Text(self.main_container,
                            height=details_height, width=details_width,
                            state=DISABLED)
    self.spot_stack = Spot_Stack(self.main_container, None,
                                 self.box_details)
    self.add_headings()
    self.arrange()

  # Ronseal.
  def make_top_title(self):
    result = Frame(self.top)
    text_lbl = Label(result, text="Proserpine",
                     font=(main_font, title_pt, "bold"))
    arms_image = PhotoImage("icon.png")
    arms_lbl = Label(result, image=arms_image, height=200)
    arms_lbl.image = arms_image
    arms_lbl.pack()
    text_lbl.pack()
    return result

  # Add headings to the holster widgets.
  def add_headings(self):
    spot_grid_label = Label(self.main_container, text="Coldstore",
                            font=(main_font, big_pt, "bold"))
    spot_stack_label = Label(self.main_container, text="Spot",
                             font=(main_font, big_pt, "bold"),
                             width=spot_stack_width)
    box_details_label = Label(self.main_container, text="Box",
                              font=(main_font, big_pt, "bold"))
    spot_grid_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    spot_stack_label.grid(column=1, row=0)
    box_details_label.grid(column=2, row=0)

  # Ronseal.
  def place_spot_stack(self):
    self.spot_stack.get_top().grid(column=1, row=1,
                                   padx=standard_pad, pady=standard_pad)

  # Arrange the object's elements.
  def arrange(self):
    self.top_title.pack()
    self.subtitle.pack()
    self.spot_grid.get_top().grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=N,
                                  padx=standard_pad, pady=standard_pad,
                                  ipadx=inner_pad, ipady=inner_pad)
    self.place_spot_stack()
    self.box_details.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N,
                          padx=standard_pad, pady=standard_pad)
    self.main_container.pack()

  # Replace the spot stack widget.
  def replace_spot_stack(self):
    self.spot_stack.get_top().grid_forget()
    self.place_spot_stack()

  # Ronseal.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

################################
# HELPER CLASSES AND FUNCTIONS #
################################

# A class which holds the grid of spots.
class Spot_Grid:
  def __init__(self, parent, parent_window):
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent_window = parent_window
    self.top = Frame(self.parent_window, borderwidth=grid_border,
                     relief="solid")
    Thread(target=self.make_grid).start()

  # Fill the grid with boxes.
  def make_grid(self):
    cs = self.parent.parent.coldstore
    for i in range(len(cs.columns)):
      column_label = Label(self.top, text=str(index_to_label_column(i)),
                           font=(main_font, big_pt, "bold"))
      column_label.grid(column=(i+1), row=0, padx=standard_pad)
      for j in range(len(cs.columns[0].spots)):
        if i == 0:
          row_label = Label(self.top, text=str(index_to_label_row(j)),
                            font=(main_font, big_pt, "bold"))
          row_label.grid(column=0, row=(j+1), padx=standard_pad)
        tile = Spot_Tile(self, self.parent, cs.columns[i].spots[j],
                         self.parent.box_details)
        tile.get_top().grid(column=(i+1), row=(j+1))

  # Ronseal.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

# A class which holds a clickable representation of a spot.
class Spot_Tile:
  def __init__(self, parent, main_ref, spot_obj, box_details_ref):
    self.parent = parent
    self.main_ref = main_ref
    self.spot_obj = spot_obj
    self.box_details_ref = box_details_ref
    self.parent_window = self.parent.get_top()
    self.top = Frame(self.parent_window)
    Thread(target=self.make_filling).start()

  # Fill the object with either a tile or a label.
  def make_filling(self):
    if self.spot_obj.max_layers == 0:
      filling = Label(self.top, text="VOID", font=(main_font, diddy_pt),
                      width=tile_width)
    elif self.spot_obj.layers() == 0:
      filling = Button(self.top, text="free", command=None,
                       font=(main_font, diddy_pt, "italic"),
                       width=tile_width, state=DISABLED)
    else:
      filling = self.make_filling_button()
    filling.pack()

  # Make the filling object if it is a button.
  def make_filling_button(self):
    result = Button(self.top, text=self.make_filling_button_text(),
                    command=self.inspect,
                    font=(main_font, diddy_pt), width=tile_width)
    return result

  # Make the text portion of the filling button.
  def make_filling_button_text(self):
    growers = set()
    varieties = set()
    fields = set()
    for box in self.spot_obj.boxes:
      current_epc = box.epc
      current_data = data_storage.fetch_most_recent_crop(current_epc)
      growers.add(current_data["grower"])
      varieties.add(current_data["variety"])
      fields.add(current_data["field"])
    result = (set_to_string(growers)+"\n"+set_to_string(varieties)+"\n"+
              set_to_string(fields)+"\n"+str(len(self.spot_obj.boxes)))
    return result

  # Inspect a given spot.
  def inspect(self):
    self.main_ref.spot_stack = Spot_Stack(self.main_ref.main_container,
                                          self.spot_obj,
                                          self.box_details_ref)
    self.main_ref.replace_spot_stack()

  # Ronseal.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

# A class which holds a representation of the boxes on a given spot.
class Spot_Stack:
  def __init__(self, parent_window, spot_obj, box_details_ref):
    self.parent_window = parent_window
    self.spot_obj = spot_obj
    self.box_details_ref = box_details_ref
    self.top = Frame(self.parent_window)
    if self.spot_obj is None:
      self.fill_empty()
    else:
      Thread(target=self.add_boxes).start()

  # "Fill in" the representation if the spot object is empty.
  def fill_empty(self):
    label = Label(self.top, text="Select spot",
                  font=(main_font, standard_pt, "italic"), width=tile_width)
    label.pack()

  # Add representations of the spot's boxes.
  def add_boxes(self):
    no_of_boxes = len(self.spot_obj.boxes)
    if no_of_boxes == 0:
      empty_label = Label(self.top, text="Empty spot",
                          font=(main_font, standard_pt, "italic"),
                          width=tile_width)
      empty_label.pack()
    else:
      for i in range(no_of_boxes):
        backwards_index = (no_of_boxes-1)-i
        box_tile = Box_Tile(self.top, self.spot_obj.boxes[backwards_index],
                            backwards_index, self.box_details_ref)
        box_tile.get_top().pack()

  # Ronseal.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

# A class which holds a clickable representation of a box.
class Box_Tile:
  def __init__(self, parent_window, box, index, box_details_ref):
    self.parent_window = parent_window
    self.box = box
    self.index = index
    self.box_details_ref = box_details_ref
    self.top = Frame(self.parent_window)
    self.make_filling()

  # Fill the object with either a tile or a label.
  def make_filling(self):
    label = Label(self.top, text=str(index_to_label_layer(self.index)),
                  font=(main_font, standard_pt))
    filling = Button(self.top, text=self.box.epc, command=self.inspect,
                     font=(main_font, standard_pt), width=tile_width)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=standard_pad)
    filling.grid(column=1, row=0)

  # Ronseal.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

  # Inspect the data for this particular box in more detail.
  def inspect(self):
    text_to_insert = data_storage.fetch_most_recent_crop(self.box.epc)
    self.box_details_ref.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.box_details_ref.delete("1.0", END)
    self.box_details_ref.insert(END, text_to_insert)
    self.box_details_ref.config(state=DISABLED)

# Turns a set into a string, with items thereof separated by commas.
def set_to_string(the_set):
  result = ""
  the_list = list(the_set)
  # Reversal is necessary, since .add() seems to add items to the FRONT of
  # the set.
  the_list.reverse()
  for item in the_list:
    if the_list.index(item) == 0:
      result = item
    else:
      result = result+", "+item
  return result
```

This is the other file, which, with its fellow, makes up the whole program:

```py
### This code holds a class which manages transitions between windows, and
### also oversees their interactions with the Coldstore object.

# Imports.
from pathlib import Path

# GUI imports.
from tkinter import *

# Custom imports.
from sibstructures.coldstore import Coldstore

# Local imports.
from cs_viewer import CS_Viewer

# Constants.
path_to_db = str(Path.home())+"/cseye/source/proserpine/data.db"

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

# The class in question.
class Comptroller:
  def __init__(self):
    self.coldstore = Coldstore(proserpine_mode=True,
                               proserpine_path=path_to_db)
    self.gui = Tk()
    self.top = Frame(self.gui)
    self.window = CS_Viewer(self)
    self.arrange()

  # Return the top-level GUI object.
  def get_top(self):
    return self.top

  # Arrange the widgets.
  def arrange(self):
    self.window.get_top().pack()
    self.top.pack()

  # Run the "mainloop" method on the GUI object.
  def run_me(self):
    self.gui.title("Proserpine")
    self.gui.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file="icon.png"))
    self.gui.mainloop()

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
  comptroller = Comptroller()
  comptroller.run_me()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run()
```

Comment: Why do you think that python garbage-collected your image? Can you show us the checking code for it?

Comment: I've posted all the code for this program, as requested.

Comment: `PhotoImage("...")` should be `PhotoImage(file="...")` in your first posted code block.

Comment: @acw1668 Bother. You're quite right. It works exactly as intended now. Should I answer my own question, or would you prefer to get in first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `PhotoImage("...")` is wrong.  It should be `PhotoImage(file="...")`.

Comment: Thank you so much!